# Constrain lower limit of the result of a subtraction

Tags: r, limit, min

I want to subtract the values in a vector from a scalar. However, if the result is lower than zero I want to set the result to zero.

I have tried using `max`, but it doesn't give me the expected result

```
s
# [1]  750.0  975.0 1125.0 1237.5 1312.5 1400.0

max(1050 - s, 0)
# [1] 300
```

I expect result to be `c(300, 150,  0,  0,  0,  0)`

Comment: Than answer is on the max help page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest `pmax`:

```
pmax(1050 - s, 0)
# [1] 300  75   0   0   0   0
```